# Dynamic text entry with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Let me preface this by saying that I am currently a JavaScript beginner, and would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction, as I am currently at a bit of a loss.

I found this pen written in Vue.js. It does a few things, but I am interested in the function wherein text appears in plain html as you type data in the field.

I was wondering how this could be accomplished with JavaScript?

https://codepen.io/mitchell-boland/pen/NVZyjX

```
computed: {
      // Think of this as live updates
      reverseString: function() {
        if(this.task) {
          return this.task.split('').reverse().join('')
        }}}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's relatively straightforward. You can listen for the "input" event on the textbox and copy the current value of the textbox into another element.

In the case of your example, the text is also being reversed at the same time, for which you need a little bit of extra code.

Here's a runnable demo:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("textIn");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

//listen to the "input" event and run the provided function each time the user types something
input.addEventListener("input", function() {
  //this line reverses the typed value
  var textOut = this.value.split("").reverse().join("")
  //write the output to another element
  output.innerText = textOut;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textIn" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

P.S. You didn't mention the reversing of text in your question, so if you don't want it you can simplify the above by removing that line and writing the value of the input box directly into the div element, e.g.

```
var input = document.getElementById("textIn");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

//listen to the "input" event and run the provided function each time the user types something
input.addEventListener("input", function() {
  //write the output to another element
  output.innerText = this.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll post this as answer:
If you're wondering how the input text turns to a reversed text in the pen, then you might need this:

```
function reverseText(txt){
  document.getElementById("#output").innerText = txt.split("").reverse().join("");
}

<input type="text" onkeyup="reverseText(this.value)" />
<p id="output"></p>
```